# Using ICommand events with custom button in a ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a control template for a ComboBox that has a button on the Popup segment of the ComboBox.

How do I react to the "Other" button click using the ICommand interface?

```
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
  IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}">
                <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" 
    MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
    MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
    BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" CornerRadius="3">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderThickness="0" Padding="1">
                        <StackPanel>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                        <Button>Other</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>

                </Border>

            </Popup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While H.B.'s answer will work, a more unobtrusive way to do this is through a new [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

Let's call it MoreCommand.

You bind the Button to MoreCommand in the control template and bind MoreCommand to the command on the ViewModel at the point you declare the ComboBox instances.

Details.

1.) You create a static class that provides an attached property

```
public static class AttachedCommand
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(AttachedCommand));

    public static bool GetCommand(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        return (bool)dependencyObject.GetValue(CommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject dependencyObject, bool value)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }
}
```

2.) You add support to your control template for this attached property

```
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
  IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}">
                <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" 
    MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
    MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
    BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" CornerRadius="3">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderThickness="0" Padding="1">
                        <StackPanel>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                        <Button Command={TemplateBinding local:AttachedCommand.Command}>Other</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
```

Make sure that you define the "local" namespace.

3.) In your view, you bind the attached property to you view model

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding Items} local:AttachedCommand.Command={Binding FetchMoreItems} />
```

The advantage is that you don't need to subclass Combobox, and you could potentially combine multiple "customizations" of the same control in the future, without the risk of class explosion.

Comment: So would there be a property on the combo box ComboBox.MoreCommand that I can set the command on, which would then be an ICommand in my view model?

Comment: Added implementation details to the answer, hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: I ended up having to go for a work-around solution due to time constraints, but this will definitely be my method of choice in future. The implementation details definitely helped because i am very new to WPF. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ComboBoxes do not have any "room" for that, you could inherit from ComboBox and introduce an `ICommand` property you then can bind the `Button.Command` to.